# Powershell as much checkboxes as a collection

Tags: powershell, checkbox, collections, dynamically-generated

With PowerShell, I made a form with three tabs. In one of them, I would have several checkboxes, and each one would be named by a collection of programs listed in the registry.

```
$Prog = Get-Item -Path "HKCU:\Software\MySoftware\EXE_list\"
$Programs = $Prog.property
```

I know how to make checkboxes. But from machine to an other, I won't have the same quantity of programs listed. So it could be up to 20 checkboxes.

So is there a way to do create checkboxes dynamically?

Thanks.

Comment: I found another question that help me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278589/how-do-i-dynamically-create-check-boxes-from-an-array-using-the-form

Comment: If my answer on the other question helped you solve this, please consider upvoting it