# Perform Robocopy foreach folder in array - ONLY if corresponding checkbox is checked?

Tags: powershell, if-statement, foreach, robocopy

We have a PowerShell form, with buttons and checkboxes, and a textbox to display output;
We have 3 checkboxes labeled "folder1", "folder2" and "folder3".
We have a button for starting robocopy (no ForEach loop)
We have a textbox which displays all script output
NOTE: This already works perfectly; we just want it done with a ForEach loop instead

We want robocopy to only copy the folders (c:\folder1, c:\folder2, c:\folder3) if the corresponding checkbox is checked, with a foreach loop.

If we have a separate robocopy instance for each folder, it works perfectly and only copies a folder if a checkbox is checked. (see code below)
We just want to do it with a ForEach loop because the only this that differs in each piece of code is the name of the folder, and name of the checkbox

What we think the problem is, is that PowerShell is looking for a checkbox named "$folder" because of the "if ($folder.Checked)" code, instead of matching the name up against the array like it does with foldernames and logfiles.

An important note; we realize that not many lines of code are removed (if any at all) with this example, but when we get this to work, there will be many more folders and checkboxes than 3, so that's why we want it done this way if possible.

TL;DR:
We have a PowerShell form with checkboxes, and a button that starts a robocopy. If "folder1" checkbox is checked, "c:\src\folder1" should be copied, and so on. This already works perfectly without a ForEach loop, we just want it done with a ForEach loop instead

What is the syntax for this? See code below

THANK YOU VERY MUCH IN ADVANCE FOR ANY HELP

We have tried putting the "if ($folder.Checked)" in brackets, quotes, double quotes, single quotes and different variations of these. We also tried defining the checkboxes in a second array in different ways and then adding a second ForEach inside the existing ForEach, but it still does not check if the checkboxes are checked and sometimes it copies the same folder several times which makes sense when we tried a ForEach inside another ForEach.

This is the solution we currently have, and it works perfectly:

```
if ($folder1.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder1" "c:\dst\folder1" /l /log+:"c:\folder1.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
if ($folder2.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder2" "c:\dst\folder2" /l /log+:"c:\folder2.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
if ($folder3.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder3" "c:\dst\folder3" /l /log+:"c:\folder3.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
}
```

This does not work:

```
$Folders = @('folder1','folder2','folder3')
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    if ($folder.Checked) { ##<-- Fails here because it looks for a checkbox named "$folder" instead of going through the array for names##
        robocopy "c:\src\$Folder" "c:\dst\$Folder" /l /log+:"c:\$Folder.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
       } else {$outputBox.AppendText("$folder NOT SELECTED" + "`r`n")}
}
}
```

This ForEach loop also WORKS perfectly (but without checkboxes) so we know it's not the ForEach loop there is anything wrong with:

```
$Folders = @('folder1','folder2','folder3')
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
        robocopy "c:\src\$Folder" "c:\dst\$Folder" /l /log+:"c:\$Folder.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
       }
}
}
```

Expected result:
Copy a folder only if corresponding checlbox is checked, with a ForEach loop. We cannot get PowerShell to check for checked checkboxes when using ForEach, only without ForEach

Full code for form:

```
#ENABLE VISUALSTYLES#
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------GUI FORM + CONSOLE OUTPUT (TEXTBOX)----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(1100,771)
$form.FormBorderStyle = "FixedDialog"
$form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$form.Topmost = $False
$form.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)

#CONSOLE OUTPUT#
$outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(240,110) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(850,500)
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Both" #"Vertical","Horizontal" 
$outputBox.BackColor = "White"
$outputBox.WordWrap = $False
$outputBox.ReadOnly = $True
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox)        

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------BUTTONS----------------------------------------------------------------------------#      
$3Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$3Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,270)
$3Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,20)
$3Button.Text = "foreach robocopy test"
#$3Button.Add_Click({RobocopyForEveryCheckbox})
$3Button.Add_Click({RobocopyForEach})
$form.Controls.Add($3Button)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------CHECKBOXES----------------------------------------------------------------------------#
$folder1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$folder1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,55)
$folder1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,20)
$folder1.Checked=$True
$folder1.Text = "Folder1"
$form.Controls.Add($folder1)

$folder2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$folder2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,75)
$folder2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,20)
$folder2.Checked=$True
$folder2.Text = "Folder2"
$form.Controls.Add($folder2)

$folder3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$folder3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,95)
$folder3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,20)
$folder3.Checked=$True
$folder3.Text = "Folder3"
$form.Controls.Add($folder3)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------FUNCTIONS----------------------------------------------------------------------------#

##############THIS FUNCTION WORKS PERFECTLY###############
function RobocopyForEveryCheckbox {
if ($folder1.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder1" "c:\dst\folder1" /l /log+:"c:\folder1.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
if ($folder2.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder2" "c:\dst\folder2" /l /log+:"c:\folder2.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
if ($folder3.Checked) {
 robocopy "c:\src\folder3" "c:\dst\folder3" /l /log+:"c:\folder3.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
 }
}

###############THIS FUNCTION DOES -NOT- WORK. BUT IT WORKS PERFECTLY IF WE DO NOT CHECK FOR CHECKED BOXES BUT IT'S THE ONE WE WANT TO USE#########################
function RobocopyForEach {
$Folders = @('folder1','folder2','folder3')
foreach ($Folder in $Folders) {
    if ($folder.Checked) { ###<-----Fails here because it looks for a checkbox named "$folder" instead of going through the array for names and so it cannot find a checkbox named "$folder" because no such exists##
        robocopy "c:\src\$Folder" "c:\dst\$Folder" /l /log+:"c:\$Folder.txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | foreach {$outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n")}
        } else {$outputBox.AppendText("$folder NOT SELECTED" + "`r`n")}
}
}

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Even though Powershell variable names are case-insensitive, I think you should go for consistency. Using both $Folder and $folder seems confusing at least to me.

Comment: Thank you for your input. We will do that refinement when we get all the functions to work

Comment: You could create the checkboxes from an array like [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32278589/how-do-i-dynamically-create-check-boxes-from-an-array-using-the-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just loose the quotes:

```
$checkbox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$checkbox1.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,55)
$checkbox1.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(110,20)
$checkbox1.Checked = $True
$checkbox1.Text = "Folder1"
$checkbox1.Tag = "c:\Custom-Files"
$form.Controls.Add($checkbox1)

$checkbox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$checkbox2.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,75)
$checkbox2.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,20)
$checkbox2.Checked = $True
$checkbox2.Text = "Folder2"
$checkbox2.Tag = "c:\somefolder"
$form.Controls.Add($checkbox2)

$checkbox3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox
$checkbox3.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,95)
$checkbox3.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(130,20)
$checkbox3.Checked = $True
$checkbox3.Text = "Folder3"
$checkbox3.Tag = "c:\anotherfolder"
$form.Controls.Add($checkbox3)

function RobocopyForEach 
{
    $checkboxes = @($checkbox1, $checkbox2, $checkbox3)

    foreach ($checkbox in $checkboxes) 
    {
        if ($checkbox.Checked) 
        {
            robocopy "c:\src\$($checkbox.Tag)" "c:\dst\$($checkbox.Tag)" /l /log+:"c:\$($checkbox.Tag).txt" /njh /njs /ndl /np /tee | ForEach-Object { $outputBox.AppendText($_ + "`r`n") }
        } 
        else 
        {
            $outputBox.AppendText("$($checkbox.Text) NOT SELECTED" + "`r`n")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solved our problem! Thank you so much, we have spent hours upon hours trying to fix this. Your help is much appreciated. -What if we give the checkboxes different names than the folders, for example "checkbox1", "checkbox2" and so on, instead of the same names as is this example? We assume we would have to create a second array for the checkboxes like so: "$checkboxes = @($checkbox1, $checkbox2, $checkbox3)" - how would we then use that instead of ``` if ($folder.Checked) ``` Thank you

Comment: If you have a fixed number of folders with fixed names, you could just rename everything to checkbox instead of folder. It might be smarter to add checkboxes and editboxes from a loop to the form, and iterate those for the copy statements

Comment: We have a fixed number of folders and checkboxes, and an equal number of both. 3 in this example. But in the example you provided me, both the folders and checkboxes are defined from the $folders array, being named "folder1, 2 and 3". But what if only the folders are named "folder1,2 and 3" and the checkboxes are instead named "checkbox1, 2 and 3"? How would this line go then: "if ($folder.Checked)". We tried defining a second array like so: "$checkboxes = @($checkbox1, $checkbox2, $checkbox3)" and then "if ($checkbox.Checked)" but unfortunately did not work. Thank you very much

Comment: That's what I meant. Rename the folder vars to checkbox and use the text field from the checkbox for the foldername. See updated answer

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. In the updated version, the checkboxnames and folder paths names are still identical, like in your previous example. We don't mean the checkbox label text, but the actual checkbox variable name. A concrete example is, one of our checkboxes are called "$checkboxCustom = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.checkbox" while the folder to copy if that checkbox is checked is called "c:\Custom-Files" so the array does not cover both. How would one go about that? We realize we could rename so they are are identical but we'd prefer this way if possible. Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use the `Tag` property for this, see updated answer

Comment: This is exactly what we needed. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array or strings and are looping through that.

This is what your code is seeing.

```
Foreach($Folder in $Folders) {
    If([String]Folder1.Checked) {
    }
}
```

What you want is to create an array of object.

```
$Folders = @("$folder1","$folder2","$folder3")
```

This should allow you to iterate through the objects and check their state.

```
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 1
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 0
System.Windows.Forms.CheckBox, CheckState: 0
```

You can then get either 1 (True) or 0 (False) by doing

```
($folder.Split(": "))[3]
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.
If we put the array like this: 
```$Folders = @("$folder1","$folder2","$folder3")
```
then the robocopy fails because it says it cannot find a folder named $folder1, $folder2 or $folder3 (apparently it takes the dollar sign as a part of the folder path.
How would we implement your suggestions in our Function?
Thank you, much appreciated